# Springboot @Transaction with JPA not working with example on the net

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, transactions

I need transaction handling in my springboot web application but transaction handling does not work. I know there are tons of example on net and I tried many in last three days. And today I found an example what I could download and try it: https://github.com/vinothr/spring-boot-transactional-example

I changed only the database url/name/pass in the yaml file but nothing else. Transactions still not working (tested with Postman) :-( I'm using mysql database and I've already set autocommit to 0 in the mysql console.

I wonder if anybody else can use the example above for transaction handling. So far, the example created the two test in my database without any transaction log in output window.

Thanks any advice
Laszlo

Comment: Could you please add your code here?

Comment: what doesn't work? Rollback? Committing?

Comment: rollback doesn't work.

Comment: I thought it is easier to check the code on github and not copy-past here. But if it's help I do this :)

Comment: Interesting... it works with h2 database. But not with mysql (InnoDB, not myIsam).

Comment: Finally, I found the problem. I should use this: database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect  and not org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect